# Capturing console stream input

Tags: c#, input, console, stream

I would like to make a console application (c# 3.5) which reads stream input.

Like this:

dir > MyApplication.exe

The app reads each line and outputs something to the console.

Which way to go?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a pipe (`|`) to pipe the output of the `dir` into the application. Redirect (`>`) that you have used in your example will trunk the file `Application.exe` and write the output of `dir` command there, thus, corrupting your application.

To read the data from the console, you have to use [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) method, for example:

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string line;
      do { 
         line = Console.ReadLine();
         if (line != null) 
            Console.WriteLine("Something.... " + line);
      } while (line != null);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Console.[Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx)/[ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) to read from the standard input stream.

Alternatively, you can get direct access to the stream (as a TextReader) via [Console.In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.in.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A practice to add in your window app or any other type of integration is as below:

```
static public void test()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process cmd = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    cmd.Start();

    /* execute "dir" */

    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    string line;
    int i = 0;

    do
    {
        line = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
        i++;
        if (line != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Line " +i.ToString()+" -- "+ line);
    } while (line != null);

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to do and what type of stream you want to work with. Presumably, you are talking about reading a text stream (based on "the app reads each line..."). Therefore, you could do something like this:

```
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(inputStream))
    {
        string line;
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine()))
        {
            // do whatever you need to with the line
        }
    }
```

Your inputStream would derive of type System.IO.Stream (like FileStream, for example).